# Operator overloading and implicit conversion to bool in relation to safe bool idiom

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I'm sure that some of my questions may have been asked before, so please let me know :).

First, an example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    typedef void (A::*funcptr)();
    operator funcptr() {
        std::cout << "funcptr" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    if (a) {}
}
```

At `if(a)`, `operator funcptr()` is called, but I'm not exactly sure what is happening here. I'm assuming the compiler looks for a conversion from an `A` to `bool` and finds `operator functptr` which is okay, but how does conversion work with pointers to member functions?

Also, if I changed `operator funcptr()` to `operator int A::*()` it would also work, but `operator void A::*` doesn't (I get `cannot declare pointer to 'void' member`), what is the rule I am missing there? (My questions are mostly related to trying to fully understand the safe bool idiom)

Also, if I declared `operator bool()` it would take precedence, so what are there rules for precedence?

Comment: It's your job to return a `funcptr` from `operator funcptr` by the way

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Right, this is just an example illustrating my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question, if you use

```
operator int A::*() { }
```

then you are creating a conversion operator which returns a pointer to an int member.  Not a pointer to a member function.  Since you can't have members of type void,

```
operator void A::*() { }
```

isn't valid.

Comment: Thanks, I see the differences now, `int A::*()` returns a pointer to an int member whereas `operator functptr()` returns a pointer to a member function.

Comment: I know that you should use a typedef for pointer to member functions, but what would it look like without the typedef?

Comment: I believe it would be   (A::*operator void())() { ... }  but that may not actually be legal.

Comment: @Jesse: prefer typedefs when pointer to functions (and methods) are concerned, it makes the code that more readable.